# I am trying to execute a sample python program through monkey runner command prompt but facing some issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to execute the monkeyrunner command from CMD 
i installed python and Android studio and set the environment paths accordingly
after running monkeyrunner or monkeyrunner test1.py in cmd i am getting the following output

C:\Users\sniloor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools>monkeyrunner
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is client.

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.

C:\Users\sniloor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools>